# How do I create a Django superuser in ssh?

Tags: python, django, azure, ssh

I am deploying Django with PostgreSQL in Azure for a school project, per this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=bash). I am working with Django 2.1.2, and Python 3.7.5.

In the "Run Database Migrations" step of the tutorial, I am instructed to open an SSH session and run the following commands:

```
cd site/wwwroot
source /antenv/bin/activate
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

When I run the 'createsuperuser' command, I expect a prompt for a username, email address, and password, but I am not prompted for any of these. Instead, the SSH session prompts me for another input, as below:

[image]

As such, I am unable to log in to my Django installation. When I attempt a login, I receive the following error message:

[image: ProgrammingError at /admin/login/]

The traceback is at the end of this message.

I expect to be able to create a superuser in Django, and use that superuser account to configure the app. Instead, I receive the ProgrammingError message and am unable to proceed.

Any help would be gratefully received. I have Googled the various error message, searched StackOverflow, and searched YouTube for tutorials, and I have reached a roadblock.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://nicholas-blog.azurewebsites.net/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 2.1.2
Python Version: 3.7.5
Installed Applications:
['polls.apps.PollsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in login
  398.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in dispatch
  61.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  141.         if form.is_valid():

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  185.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  180.             self.full_clean()

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  382.         self._clean_form()

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  409.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean
  196.             self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  73.             user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py" in authenticate
  16.             user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py" in get_by_natural_key
  44.         return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  393.         num = len(clone)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  250.         self._fetch_all()

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1186.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1065.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Did you forget `python manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: What input does it prompt you for instead?

Comment: @Def_Os: Unfortunately, that did not lead to me being prompted for superuser credentials.

Comment: @UzziEmuchay: It does not prompt me for any input. It returns to a blank SSH input.

Comment: @NicholasSabin interesting. When you run the migrate command what happens? Based on the error  you are getting, the migrate command isn't doing its job of creating the user role in the db. Does it throw an error then?

Comment: @UzziEmuchay The SSH shell returns a blank SSH input.

Comment: Did you see the output of `migrate`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Migrate outputs a blank SSH input.

Comment: You don't get any output from your commands. Does `ls` output something? What about `python --version`?

Comment: `ls` shows the file structure I'd expect to see.

`python --version` returns `Python 3.7.5`.

Comment: And does `cat manage.py` output the expected manage.py?

Answer (score 1):

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

You might have forgotten to do makemigrations.

Comment: Unfortunately, using the makemigrations command does not change the prompt from the SSH session.

Comment: Django would run the migrations for admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions at least anyway if you didn't `makemigrations`, and that is enough to create a super user. The problem doesn't come from that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not asking for username then it might be your shell is not allowing it. You can use `--noinput` for that

```
python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username testuser --email test@gmail.com
```

You cannot set the password though, it will be set automatically you'd have to change it from admin panel.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. Unfortunately, when I try it, the shell seems to overflow, and returns another blank SSH prompt.